# Display files in a folder along with the date modified of those files

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.6

```
 <?php 
    $filename = 'file:///C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/2017/cdr'
    $files = array();
    if ($handle = opendir($filename)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
               $files[filemtime($file)] = $file;
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);

        // sort
        ksort($files);
        // find the last modification
        $reallyLastModified = end($files);

        foreach($files as $file) {
            $lastModified = date('F d Y, H:i:s',filemtime($file));
            if(strlen($file)-strpos($file,".swf")== 4){
               if ($file == $reallyLastModified) {
                 // do stuff for the real last modified file
               }
               echo "<tr><td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"box[]\"></td><td><a href=\"$file\" target=\"_blank\">$file</a></td><td>$lastModified</td></tr>";
            }
        }
    }
```

I have been trying to use this code to list and show files in a folder along with the date modified. i keep getting an error **filemtime(): stat failed**.

İ am trying listing them as arrays as an alternative using the below code

```
    <?php
    $folder = 'file:///C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/2017/cdr';
    $backups = array();
    foreach (scandir($folder) as $node) {
        $nodePath = $folder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $node;
        if (is_dir($nodePath)) continue;
        $backups[$nodePath] = filemtime($nodePath);

    }
    ksort($backups);
    print_r($backups);
```

when i run this code i get the result below and i dont know what the numbers represent.

> [file:///C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/2017/cdr\2017_0622_1500.raw] =>1498136278
>   [file:///C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/2017/cdr\2017_0622_1600.cdr] =>1498136430
>   [file:///C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/2017/cdr\2017_0622_1600.raw] =>1498139955
>   [file:///C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/2017/cdr\2017_0622_1700.raw] =>1498142424

what am trying to achieve is to be able to display the files in the CDR along with their modified dates.

Comment: Why are you adding `file:///`? Are you trying to access local files through the network? Are you trying to access files form other computers?

Comment: @Álvaro González. Trying to Access a file from computer

Comment: just use the path then (e.g. /home/user/file.txt or C:\files\file.txt depending on your O/S). `file:///` is only used in a web browser to open a local file.

Comment: @ADyson. I still get **Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for**

Comment: probably your file path is wrong or you don't have sufficient permissions to the file. Does a file with that path definitely exist on the server where PHP is executing? Does the account PHP runs under have permissions to read the file/folder

Comment: As for what the numbers returned on a successful call mean, the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php tells you what you need to know. They are UNIX timestamps. You can display them however you like by using the `date()` function. BTW all of this information you could find yourself by easily searching on google, like I've just done.

Comment: @ADyson oh i googled before i asked. Date is what i used in the first script

Comment: In that case then why did you ask what the numbers represent, if you already know what to do with them?

Comment: ADyson i actually did not know what they were. they are unique and that is all i knew. maybe i misunderstood your answer earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

    function cmp($a, $b) {
        if (filemtime($a) == filemtime($b))
            return 0;

        return (filemtime($a) < filemtime($b)) ? -1 : 1;
    }


    $files = glob("/Users/xxx/Desktop/2017/cdr/*.cdr");
    usort($files, "cmp");

    foreach($files as $file)
        //echo $file . "<br />";
        echo "$file was last modified: " . date ("d-m-Y H:i:s.", filemtime($file))."\n";
?>
```

This seemed to work. And the out put looked like this.

> /2017/cdr/2017_0330_1300.cdr last modified: 30-03-2017 10:53:23.
>   /2017/cdr/2017_0330_1500.cdr last modified: 30-03-2017 12:18:05.
>   /2017/cdr/2017_0330_1600.cdr last modified:30-03-2017 13:55:21.